# Is it ok to leave a comment when flagging a question

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to leave a comment when flagging a question, for example 'flagged for unclear', or 'flagged for low quality'.

I have seen it a few times and I've done it myself as well.

Not sure myself if this is a good thing, since it would somewhat assist the next flagger, or a bad thing, since it might start a snowball effect.

Comment: Of course, why not?

Comment: Sure.  Just be ready to be receive notification from other users who complain @closeVoter.

Comment: Just as an FYI when you cast close votes you can see what other close votes have been cast.  You cannot see who did them until the question is closed and you can never see which way each user voted but only the "Consensus".

Comment: I've done this myself; I think it helps out new users who might not even realize flagging posts is a thing. I seem to get less pushback from the OP when I say I'm flagging the post instead of just trying to tell them how to improve it. I don't see why it would cause a snowball effect since the comment itself wouldn't drive more people to the post, which is what causes the Meta effect.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it ok to leave a comment when flagging a question, for example 'flagged for unclear', or 'flagged for low quality'.

If that's all your comment would contain then no.

But if you include the "why part" to why it's not a suitable question and how to make it better, then sure, as long as no one else has left a similar comment already.

For example:

> I flagged this question for closure since you didn't provide the relevant HTML and CSS in your question, please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question so we can help you fix your issue.

Comment: And use the [edit] magic link (type `[edit]` in the comment).  Seems to help users who want to edit but don't see that small, grey edit link under their post.